# Unit testing assignment of values

Tags: unit-testing

Should I be unit testing the assignment of values from 1 or more objects to another.
For example, this could occur within a method or a builder (auto mapping could be used too).

How much value would you place on this type of test?  I guess this is subjective, the state is arbitrary but I guess there is a need to ensure the mapping is what we expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't focus on testing infrastructure - test the *business logic*. If your code (a class designed for particular purpose) correctly does what your requirements describe, then it doesn't matter whether some internal builder/method or whatever sets something "correctly" or not. On the other hand, if this part of code is important to meet your requirements then your business logic tests will surely cover it.

If the main requirement for your class is for it to correctly copy some properties, then obviously you should test for that. But not because testing setters and getters is good, but because it comes from testing if your code does what you expect it to do in terms of external requirements.

Answer (score 1):

"Should I be unit testing the assignment of values from 1 or more objects to another"

If that is the smallest unit of program you can test then yes

Start simple and build your way up

Comment: driving home the point that an expectation should be documented in a test perhaps?  It makes sense completely.  I guess I was just interested to see if there was opinion on this.